# Parsing JSON with Mantle - Swift

Tags: json, swift, metal

I'm using mantle to parse JSON data with Swift. The content of the JSON file consists of:

```
{
    "Name1": [
      {
        "Type": "New",
        "Available": true,
        "Kind": "4178228729",
        "Loot": "4367",
        "Advanced": [
          {
            "Type": "Old",
            "Name": "RoundRobin",
        "Available": true,
            "Specs": [
              {
                "Type": "Fire",
                "Available": true,

                "Actions": [


                --continues with similar pattern--
    ],
    "Name2": [
                --repeats the same pattern at before--
    ]
}
```

I created the model classes, inheriting from MTLJSONSerializing. The "first level class" is to contain the two top level arrays of objects.

```
import Foundation

class lv1Class: MTLJSONSerializing {
    let name1: Array<lv2Class> = []
    let name2: Array<lv2Class> = []


        class func name2JSONTransformer() -> NSValueTransformer {
        return NSValueTransformer.mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass(lv2Class.self)
    }

        class func name1JSONTransformer() -> NSValueTransformer {
        return NSValueTransformer.mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass(lv2Class.self)
    }

        override class func JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!
    {
        return ["name1": "Name1",
            "name2": "Name2"]
    }
}
```

And it goes on like this deeper and deeper.

```
import Foundation

class lv2Class: MTLJSONSerializing {
    let type: String = ""
    let available: Bool = true
    let kind: String = ""
    let loot: String = ""
    let advanced: Array<lv3Class> = []


        class func advancedJSONTransformer() -> NSValueTransformer {
        return NSValueTransformer.mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass(lv3Class.self)
    }

        override class func JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!
    {
        return ["type": "Type",
        "available": "Available",
        "kind": "Kind",
        "loot": "Loot",
        "advanced": "Advanced"]
    }
}
```

The other classes are similar in structure. (I can post them all on gists if necessary.)

The call to get the JSON data is as follows:

```
  if let lv1ClassObject = MTLJSONAdapter.modelOfClass(lv1Class.self, fromJSONDictionary: testDic,  error: errorjson) as? lv1Class
```

testDic is the file posted above.

The call that i make to get the json data succeeds, I'm pretty confident that the problem is in my data model. The value of the dictionary is an array so I feel pretty confident parsing it as an array.

The error I get is:

```
Assertion failure in -[MTLJSONAdapter initWithJSONDictionary:modelClass:error:], /Users/xx/Documents/Xcode/My_project/Pods/Mantle/Mantle/MTLJSONAdapter.m:149
2015-03-14 14:34:20.331 My_project[25794:711328] *** Caught exception available is not a property of My_project.lv2Class
```

But available is a property of such class...

```
 let available: Bool = true
```

Hope it's clear enough, if you have any question feel free to ask.

I'm really not familiar with parsing JSON, thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is [here](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/issues/476#issuecomment-82950080).

---

You both need to put them as  `dynamic` and to make sure that all your property can be bridged to the equivalent Obj-C property.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing this problem. I have "dynamic var allowPushNotifications: NSNumber = 0" and in the resulting model I get a null. If I change it to String I do get the expected value. Using Mantle 2 and Swift 1.2. Thanks